# Encountering NotImplementedError in Asynchronous Code with Playwright: Understanding the Cause and Seeking Solutions

Tags: web-scraping, webdriver, subprocess, python-asyncio, playwright

I encountered a `NotImplementedError` when running my asynchronous code with Playwright. Could you help me understand the root cause of this error and suggest a possible solution?

This is the code I ran: `html = await get_html(url, "#content .filter")`

but I think the error is coming from here:

```
async def get_html(url, selector, sleep=5, retries=3):
    html = None
    for i in range(1, retries+1):
        time.sleep(sleep * i)
        try:
            async with async_playwright() as p:
                browser = await p.chromium.launch()
                page = await browser.new_page()
                await page.goto(url)
                print(await page.title())
                html = await page.inner_html(selector)
        except PlaywrightTimeout:
            print(f"Timeout error on {url}")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return html
```

I changed the chromium to Firefox but it still gives me the same error

this is the code I ran: `html = await get_html(url, "#content .filter")`

this is what I was expecting:
2015-16 NBA Schedule | Basketball-Reference.com

Comment: What's the URL? This code seems OK.

Comment: You do not ever have to guess where an error is coming from in a Python program.  Look at the traceback.  Where exactly is the error?  What line of code in your program is triggering the problem?  This may not always be easy to understand in an asyncio program, but it is almost always the right place to begin troubleshooting.